# Printing next Page Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, printing

Is there a way to print the page that gets openned using `target="_blank"` with javascript (or jquery) instead of printing the current one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. A window opened using `target="_blank"` has no programmatic connection to the page it was opened from.

If it was opened with `window.open` then the return value of that call would be a reference to that window, so you could use that to get to the `print` method (subject to the same origin policy).

That said, I can't think of any reason to do this that would not be better served by a [print media style sheet.](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/)

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can use an iframe (with display:none css style) to load the url content  and then print the iframe

bye!